# PSTricks---plotstyle LSM (Least Square method)

Tags: pstricks, graphs, plot

I am discovering PSTricks's `plotstyle=LSM` to make a regression analysis `y=m x + c`. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0.0     0.0
144.321  0.84
159.407     0.8925

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\readdata{\data}{data.dat}

\psset{xunit=0.6mm,yunit=30mm,xlabelFactor=$$,labelFontSize=\footnotesize,mathLabel=false}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(150,3)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame,Dx=50,Dy=0.5, ticksize=0 4pt](150,3)
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,plotstyle=values,rot=90] {\data}
\listplot [xStart=0,xEnd=150,xunit=1,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,showpoints, dotstyle=square] {\data}
\listplot[PstDebug=1,xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,plotstyle=LSM,linecolor=blue, linestyle=dashed]{\data}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The parameter `xEnd=150` makes the Linear regression analysis only to consider the first two lines of the data file.

On compiling I get the line equation as

`y = 0.291017 x + 9.64966e-08`

I see that the gradient of `0.291017` seems to be wrong as the gradient should be `0.84/144.321 = 0.0058...`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that was a problem with different axes unit. Try it with this version:

http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot.tex

With this file it works for me.

And by the way, there is now a pst-fit, see http://texnik.dante.de/doc/generic/pst-fit/pst-fit-doc.pdf