# EPS output from PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, eps

I am trying to produce an `EPS` file from a PSTricks code. I am reproducing here the sample working code that I already have here:

[PSTricks---plotstyle LSM (Least Square method)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/pstricks-plotstyle-lsm-least-square-method)

Here is the modified code with `\PStoEPS`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0.0     0.0
144.321  0.84
159.407     0.8925

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-eps}


\begin{document}
\readdata{\data}{data.dat}
\PSTtoEPS[bbllx=0,bblly=0,bburx=0,bbury=0]{test.eps}{%
\psset{xunit=0.6mm,yunit=30mm,xlabelFactor=$$,labelFontSize=\footnotesize,mathLabel=false}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(150,3)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame,Dx=50,Dy=0.5, ticksize=0 4pt](150,3)
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,plotstyle=values,rot=90] {\data}
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,showpoints, dotstyle=square] {\data}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

My understanding is that I need to enclose all PSTricks code in th last argument of `\PStoEPS`. On compilation, no DVI file is created and no other consequent output (eps) as well. I have three questions:

1. How to properly set the `\PStoEPS` options?
2. What compilation sequence is necessary to get the `EPS` output (LaTeX > DVI2ps?)
3. Are the bounding box coordinates necessary to be specified? Will `\PStoEPS` not produce an `EPS` with tight bounding box?

Thanks a lot...

---

Update: trying to use `pst2pdf`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0.0     0.0
144.321  0.84
159.407     0.8925

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\readdata{\data}{data.dat}
\psset{xunit=0.6mm,yunit=30mm,xlabelFactor=$$,labelFontSize=\footnotesize,mathLabel=false}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(150,3)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame,Dx=50,Dy=0.5, ticksize=0 4pt](150,3)
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,plotstyle=values,rot=90] {\data}
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,showpoints, dotstyle=square] {\data}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

On a DOS prompt running the `pst2pdf` command on the above `tex` file gives:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \data

l.23 ...0,xunit=1,plotstyle=values,rot=90] {\data}

?
```

The `pst2pdf` has difficulty to understand the `\listplot` arguments.

The goal in producing an `EPS` file is also to have one with a tight bounding box. But using the document class `standalone` seems to cut away the axes and no labels or tickmarks are shown.

Comment: why do you want to create an eps?

Comment: Many academic journals are interested to have the pictures as separate (EPS) files and not embedded in the LaTeX codes.

Comment: ok, understood. Are you running Linux or Windows? However, with TeXLive comes a script `pst2pdf <file>` which creates from all pspicture environments single eps/pdf/png files in a subdirectory

Comment: Win XP with the latest TexLive 2011.

Comment: I have no experience with windows, but the script should also works. If not, then use the package `auto-pst-pdf` instead. It creates a conatiner file `<file>-pics.pdf` which collects all `pspicture` environments as a single pdf page. See http://PSTricks.tug.org` for more informations

Comment: @ Herbert I am trying to use `pst2pdf` but I got some errors.

Comment: @ Herbert Using `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` instead of `pst2pdf` is not creating an EPS file. I just get a normal PDF output as with normal LaTeX > DVI2PS > PS2PDF compilation

Comment: true, but it is easy to convert a pdf to an eps. However, for `pst2pdf` all PostScript related stuff must be inside the `pspicture` environment. If it is not possible then one can use the environment `postscript` and put the `pspicture` environment and other code into the `postscript` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embedd the `pstricks` picture into a `TeXtoEPS` environment and then use `dvips -E` to get an EPS with tight bounding box. The following works for me:

```
% compile with latex --> dvips -E
\documentclass[12pt,dvips]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0.0     0.0
144.321  0.84
159.407     0.8925

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add,pst-eps}
%\usepackage{pst-eps}

\begin{document}
\readdata{\data}{data.dat}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\psset{xunit=0.6mm,yunit=30mm,xlabelFactor=$$,labelFontSize=\footnotesize,mathLabel=false}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(150,3)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame,Dx=50,Dy=0.5, ticksize=0 4pt](150,3)
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,plotstyle=values,rot=90] {\data}
\listplot [xStart=0, xEnd=150,xunit=1,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,showpoints, dotstyle=square] {\data}
\end{pspicture}
\end{TeXtoEPS}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with:

```
latex graph.tex
dvips -E graph.dvi
```

The resulting `graph.ps` file actually is an EPS file with tight bounding box, which in the following is visualized by rendering it inside an `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
% \fbox to visualize the dimensions  
\fbox{\includegraphics{graph.ps}}
\end{document}
```

[image: scree shot of resulting page]

Comment: `dvips -E` can also be used without using the environment `TeXtoEPS`

Comment: @ Daniel Thanks. This is a `PS` file and not an `EPS`. I have tried converting the `PS` to an `EPS` file using `ps2eps -f --fixps graph.ps`. When inserting the resulting `graph.eps` file with the `\includegraphics` command I get the graph upside down and at the bottom left of the page. An `PS` takes the whole page while an `EPS` will only take the space it needs. I played with the bounding box of the `EPS` file but couldn't make it appear well. 1vote up.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: The result _is_ an EPS with tight bounding box. See my updated answer, which also demonstrates using it with `\includegraphics`. Note the `\fbox` around it, which visualized the dimensions and the page number (1) in the very bottom.

Comment: @ Daniel I guess here it is better to stick with the `PS` file rather than trying to convert it into an `EPS`. The issue for me is that I can add text above and below the image. Yes it works. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The way to change the name of the resulting `graph.ps` file to `graph.eps`,

```
dvips -E graph.dvi -o [filename].eps
```

"-o [filename].eps" is just to change the name of the produced file graph.ps by `dvips -E graph.dvi` to `[filename].eps`.
And `dvips graph.dvi  -E -o [filename].eps` is also OK.
See more: http://solvcon.net/yyc/writing/2009/pstricks_eps.html
http://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/dvips.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: actually, the eps file produced by this method may have a blank which can be seen if you use the \fbox{}, and I don't know why. But i can use latex + divips + pspdf, 
[ use \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=0pt to get the exact size you want ]

then use acrobat professional to save it as eps file, choose RGB color when saving.